# If Post Meta Equals Current Title Conditional Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I would like to create a custom query loop to display data depending on the current post title.

Pseudo-code:

```
if post title = custom filed 
    Show related content
```

I have a page called `artists` made up of custom fields and I would like to show the discography for that artist. By pulling only the posts with the artists name from the discography posts which are in another custom post type.

I found [this page](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-post-meta-equals-current-title-conditional) which is close but not quite right.

I have a custom post type called `discography`, and within this post type I have a custom field called `dis_artist`.

I am stuck being able to say if the current artist "post title" = "dis_artist" then show other data. How can I do that?

---

Hi I tried but Im not sure I have the right syntax. This piece of code sits within the current post loop

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'discography', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>            
<?php
if ( get_the_title() === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "dis_artist", true ) ) {   ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php }    ?>        
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as easy as this - as long as your `dis_artist` meta key doesn't hold an array.

```
if ( get_the_title() === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "dis_artist", true ) )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thanks for the super fast responce

Answer (score 1):

Are you using advanced custom fields or not? They have their own built in functions that look for the custom field.

```
if (get_field('dis_artist'))
{
   //do stuff here
   // the_field('dis_artist') is the same as $dis_artist = dis_artist; echo $dis_artist
}
```

Your title is slightly confusing.

If you set the ACF field to a variable, you can then test it inside your loop:

```
 if (get_field('your_acf_field')
 {
    $your_acf_field = get_field('your_acf_field');
 }


$args = array( 'post_type' => 'discography', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if ($your_acf_field == the_title()) : echo the_title();

else :

 //do something else here if it is not

endif;

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This code isn't tested, so you may need to tweak it. But it tests if the acf field is set, if it is, it sets it to a variable. Inside of the loop, you then test to see if the title is equal to the variable. If it is, it displays it. If not, you can have it do something else, like echo "Not Found";

Comment: Yes I am using ACF. I added the code here but. Im really stuck! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67043/query-post-title-within-another-loop

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried but Im not sure I have the right syntax. This piece of code sits within the current post loop

```
<!-- Start the main loop -->
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

I want to use this title as the main reference to query against the custom filed

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'discography', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>            
<?php
if ( get_the_title() === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "dis_artist", true ) ) {   ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php }    ?>        
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?> <!-- End the main loop -->
```